# Пунктуация. Придаточное внутри главного

Tags: пунктуация

"И как бы он ребёнком не проводил эту прекрасную пору, всегда найдётся то, что человек впоследствии сможет назвать своей малой родиной." Должна ли стоять после первой "и" запятая? Или она необязательна в данном случае? Почему? Хотелось бы, по возможности, ссылку на конкретное правило.

Answer (score 3):

После присоединительного союза И запятая обычно не ставится:

**И как бы он ребёнком НИ проводил эту прекрасную пору, всегда найдётся то, что человек впоследствии сможет назвать своей малой родиной.**

Розенталь [§ 36. Запятая на стыке двух союзов](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=140#pp140)

5. Постановка запятой между присоединительным союзом и следующим за ним подчинительным союзом зависит от значения союза:
   1) **как правило, после союза И запятая не ставится:** И когда Левинсон, выполнив все будничные дела, отдал наконец приказ выступать, — в отряде наступило такое ликование, точно с этим приказом на самом деле кончались всякие мытарства (Ф.); И хотя погода значительно улучшилась, опасность засухи не миновала; И вместо того чтобы свернуть направо, по ошибке поехали прямо.

**Примечание. Семантика предложения выражена недостаточно ясно**. Предлагается редактирование в качестве варианта:

И как бы он ребёнком НИ проводил эту прекрасную пору, остается чувство любви к родному краю,  и  всегда найдётся то место, которое человек впоследствии сможет назвать своей малой родиной.

Comment: Это сообщение заслуживало минуса, удаленного модератором. "И" здесь не союз, а частица. Розенталь не утверждает иного, цитата не к месту.

Answer (score 3):

У  Розенталя (по ссылке Sibylla) есть примечание:

3) перед придаточной частью запятая ставится в зависимости от значения присоединительного союза и наличия/отсутствия паузы при чтении. [См. § 36, п. 5.]

Следовательно, есть варианты, ставить или нет запятую после И. В вопросе Вы уточнили: **придаточное внутри главного**. В этом случае, конечно, запятая нужна:

[И,( как бы он ребёнком ни проводил эту прекрасную пору), всегда найдётся то], (что человек впоследствии сможет назвать своей малой родиной). В этом варианте "И" относится к главному предложению: И всегда найдётся то, что...

Но Вам пытаются объяснить, что при такой структуре предложения, когда И находится в абсолютном начале предложения, оно является не союзом, а частицей и относится  чаще всего к последующей предикативной части, т.е. придаточному предложению. Мы не знаем всех обстоятельств Вашей ситуации, значит, Вам решать, к чему относится И.  Если к придаточному, то запятой нет, если к главному, то запятая есть. Об этом и говорит Розенталь в примечании.

Comment: Людмила, а что вы скажете насчет не/ни тут? Мне кажется, что тут НИ ("не" просто невозможно)  - и уже поэтому запятая просто "не смотрится" ни по каким правилам.

Comment: Людмила, а где у Розенталя сказано, что И является ЧАСТИЦЕЙ? И относительно союзов И, А сказано, что после них запятая ОБЫЧНО не ставится. Что же тут изобретать, думать о вставочной интонации для придаточного. Стандартное предложение, для которого предложено стандартное решение. Люди сюда за ответами приходят, а не для того чтобы видеть, как Мимоходов всем минусы расставляет и получает двойной минус в ответ. Как вы думаете, такая картина прибавляет нам доверия и уважения с их стороны? Просто беспредел какой-то, надо что-то с этим делать. Неужели один человек может остановить работу всего сайта

Comment: По-моему, все высказанные мнения интересны. Я всем добавляю плюс.

Comment: Мимоходов, здесь  (не "тут"), конечно, НИ, вернее КАК БЫ НИ, - союзные слова в обобщённо-уступительном придаточном предложении, но при чём здесь "смотрится - не смотрится"? Нет такого правила, нужно смотреть структуру предложения.

Comment: Sibylla, разве И здесь что-то соединяет? Или всё-таки усиливает? А если усиливает, значит, частица. А вот про "изобретать" и вовсе несерьёзно. Обычно не ставится, но если И относится к главному предложению, а придаточное начинается после И, то ставится. Автор же ставит такое условие: придаточное внутри главного, Вы не заметили? Мы отвечаем на его вопрос, а не изобретаем свой.

Comment: @Людмила, честно говоря, я тоже не понял: почему вы считаете, что И в начале придаточного предложения является частицей?

Answer (score 0):

Запятая не нужна, а предложение очень небрежное и корявое.

1. "Он" и "человек" – одно и то же? Видимо, нет. "Он" – речь явно идёт о конкретном человеке. "Человек" употреблено в значении "каждый человек". Неряшливо.
2. Можно ли "проводить пору"?
3. Почему "впоследствии"?

Answer (score 0):

В начале предложения (в том числе и внутри ССП) **И** обычно не союз, а усилительная частица, перед вопросительным словом в значении усиления - всегда. Запятая не нужна, поскольку эта частица относится к "как (бы ни)".

> Произошли многие изменения в жизни тех, кто пострадал от Воланда и его
>   присных, и как бы ни были мелки и незначительны эти изменения, всё же
>   следует их отметить. М. А. Булгаков. Мастер и Маргарита, часть 2
>   (1929-1940)
>
> И как бы ни были несовершенны органы исполнительной власти, во всяком
>   случае безопаснее и вернее поручить им дело защиты граждан от этих
>   злоупотреблений, чем оставить это на произвол частной саморасправы».
>   [Б. А. Кистяковский. В защиту права (1909)]
>
> И как бы ни был этот запах заглушаем горячим потом взмыленных
>   паломников, волокущих деревянный крест по Виа Долороса, как бы ни
>   перешибала его грубая вонь подозрительного мыла дешевых постоялых
>   дворов, сколь бы ни примешивался к нему хлебный дух длинных пресных
>   кренделей, что продают арабы с тележек, ― тревожащий, тонкий,
>   всепроникающий запах ладана царит не только в храмах и церквах, но и
>   на улицах Христианского квартала . [Дина Рубина. Медная шкатулка
>   (сборник) (2015)]
>
> И как бы ни пытались некоторые высокопоставленные чиновники, воюя с
>   образованием и наукой, опустить нас поближе к уровню Нигерии, они
>   получают лишь растущее сопротивление материала. [Борис Кагарлицкий.
>   Между «тиграми» и «бананами» // «Русская жизнь», 2012]

(Нацкорпус)

Там есть и несколько примеров, когда запятая после "И" (то есть И понимается как союз) - но не в начале фразы.

Comment: Откуда три анонимных минуса без объяснения причин? Почему  это точка зрения не имеет права на существование? Грамота признает, что "и" может быть частицей (http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B8&all=x)

Comment: @М_Г, не напрягайтесь. Здесь не просто "признает" и "может быть", здесь очевидная частица. Что и доказывают многочисленные примеры. А минусы - от авторов, не различающих "ни" и "не".

Comment: *Частица И - усилительная. В отличие от союза И, она не связывает однородные члены или части сложного предложения. Например: "И это все о нем", "И я там был".* - это, согласен, не авторитетный источник, но простите, Розенталь не писал о вещах, которые в школе проходят. К тому же теория частиц довольно новая штука.